# Xml schema to separate 'data' from 'preferences'

Tags: xml

I'm designing an XML document to store some data, that can also have some settings/customisation on it set by a user.

I'd like to keep the data stuff that the system defines separate from the customisation by the user.

Apalling example:

```
<example>
  <data>
    <fruit name="apple" maxCount="20" />
  </data>
  <settings>
    <fruit name="apple" colour="pink" size="40" />
  </settings>
</example>
```

This achieves what I want, but there is no obvious link between the two nodes, and I would have to use the name to cross-reference.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keys and keyrefs in XML schema to define and enforce such links. There is a decent tutorial: [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/29/schemas/part1.html?page=6)